# Null Checks for long datatype in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a problem where I need to first query the database to determine if the input record will result in 'overlapping' date spans. Fairly simple task in SQL, but I cannot seem to get it to work in Linq. Here are the relevant business rules:

If Id1 == Id1 and the datespans overlap, then bring me back the record(s) that conflict
If Id2 == Id2 and the datespans overlap, then bring me back the record(s) that conflict
If Id1 == null and Id2 == null and the datespans overlap, then bring me back the records that conflict.

My linq query is as follows:

```
resultingOverlaps = (from overlapSpans in entities.ENTITIES
             where overlapSpans.CNTRCT_TYP_ID == contractId
             where (overlapSpans.ID1 == Id1 || overlapSpans.Id2 == Id2 ||
                   (overlapSpans.ID1 == null && overlapSpans.Id2 == null))
             where (
             (overlapSpans.EFF_DT < effDate && overlapSpans.END_DT >= effDate)
              || (overlapSpans.EFF_DT > effDate && overlapSpans.EFF_DT <= endDate)
              || (overlapSpans.EFF_DT == effDate)
             )
             select overlapSpans).ToList();
```

The issue is that Id1 and Id2 are the datatype long?, and thus cannot be checked for null in this manner, or any other manner that I have tried so far. (testing for 0, using '.HasValue', etc.)

How do you check for null values that have a long datatype?

Comment: Have you looked into `HasValue` for nullable types? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah, my post says that I have tried this.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that bit. Does your code compile and run, or does it not even build?

Comment: It compiles and runs just fine, it executes this linq query, but in the case of Id1 == null && Id2 == null it returns no records (there are plenty of cases it should return), and thus I hit a uniqueness constraint error on the insert.

Comment: What type do the properties ID1 and ID2 have?

Comment: They are long? types

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, have you tried using `object.Equals` to compare the IDs?

Comment: does overlapSpans.ID1 == DBNull.Value  work?

Comment: @hunch_hunch, I did try overlapSpans.Id1.Equals(null), and that didnt work either.

Comment: Could you rename your input variables in your question so they are not being confused with the columns from the table? I'm not sure but I think you need `where (Id1==null && Id2==null) || (overlapSpans.ID1 == Id1 || overlapSpans.Id2 == Id2)`, because you want to select records when the input is null, not those records where the database columns are NULL (which is what you are doing right now).

Comment: @Yogee, no that won't work. Using '== DBNull.Value' produces an error, and .Equals(DBNull.Value) gives me a runtime error.

Comment: @AVee, Good catch, I do need to allow for these cases (where there exists a record where both IDcolumns are null, but one of the input variables is not null). However, this is not my issue. My issue is where I am trying to pull out records where both IDColumns ARE null, and I cannot find the equivalence condition that matches this case.

Comment: Have you tried running the most basic null query you can? E.g. `(from overlapSpans in entities.ENTITIES where overlapSpans.ID1 == null)` That will verify whether checking for null values works, once you're sure you've got the null check covered you can look at the actual query again.

Comment: @AVee, Just did that. Not sure what my issue WAS, but the query works now. The final adjustments I made were: 
- Adding a check for the input variables, ensuring theyre null
- Using '== null'

Must have been your first suggestion all along. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If entity framework is creating these properties as "long" that means that the column must be designated as "NOT NULL" in the database.

There is no need to check for null because overlapSpans.ID1 and overlapSpans.Id2 will never be null.

If they could be null, EF is smart enough to make their data types "long?" (Nullable< Int64>).

Also a variable typed as long cannot be null in the first place. They have a default value of "0" (verify with default(Int64)) so if they were "null" they would equal "0".